# Firefox: Addon- Buttons don't appear in Browser

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, adblock

There are 2 user accounts on my computer. User Account #1 is Administrator, User Account #2 is an normal account. 
Both Accounts use Firefox as Browser and almost the same add-ons.

[image]

Lately I wanted to change the settings on User Account #2 for the add-on "adblock plus". More precisely: I wanted to deactivate Adblock plus for special websites (where I accept ads). This is usually possible with clicking on the adblock plus button next to the search bar (I marked it on the photo). But as you can see on the photo: User Account #2 doesn't have that button (or any other addons like the WOT-button) visible in the browser. I don't have access to it.

**My question:** *How can I manage that those addons are viewed in the browser directly? Because until they don't appear in the browser bar, I cannot access to my desired functionality. I cannot manage this via Firefox -> Addons...*

P.S.: checking "Add-on-bar" via Firefox -> options doesn't let the adblock plus button appear on the bottom corner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Right-click the toolbar (pretty much in between the address bar and the search box) and click **Customize...**
   [image]
2. In the resulting dialog, locate the button for the extension you're looking for.
   [image]
3. Now, by using drag & drop, drop the button at your desired location in the toolbar.
   [image]